# Cocos3d on Android

Tags: android, cocos3d

I have developped an application that uses Cocos3D on iPhone. Now I want to develop the same application on android using Cocos3D. Can anyone help me on how to install and use Cocos3D on android?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porting to Android is very easy with **Cocos3D**. **Cocos3D** has partnered with [Apportable](http://apportable.com) to bring your 3D apps and games to the Android platform. The Apportable SDK is a free SDK for porting Objective-C applications to Android.

Use the Apportable site to get familiar with their product. The `README.md` file within the **Cocos3D** distribution contains some instructions.